# Sum price of a table with reference to two others - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

I have these three tables and I want to get the sum of the price field of table 3 linked to table 1, table 2 being linked to table 1 and 3:

Table 1 - Tecnic

```
+--------------+------------+
|   id_tecnic  |   name     |
+--------------+------------+
|       1      |  Michael   |
|       2      |  Billy     |
|       3      |  Joe       |
+--------------+------------+
```

Table 2 - Linked

```
+--------------+------------+------------+
|   id_linked  | id_tecnic  |    id_mer  |
+--------------+------------+------------+
|       1      |     1      |     4      |
|       2      |     3      |     1      |
|       3      |     3      |     2      |
+--------------+------------+------------+
```

Table 3 - Mer

```
+--------------+------------+
|    id_mer    |    price   |
+--------------+------------+
|       1      |     30     |
|       2      |     70     |
|       3      |     50     |
|       4      |     10     |
+--------------+------------+
```

Result

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+
|   id_tecnic  |   name     | total_price |
+--------------+------------+-------------+
|       1      |  Michael   |      10     |
|       2      |  Billy     |       0     |
|       3      |  Joe       |      90     |
+--------------+------------+-------------+
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT te.id_tecnic, 
SUM(m.price)
FROM tecnic te
LEFT JOIN linked l ON te.id_tecnic = l.id_tecnic
LEFT JOIN mer m ON l.id_mer = m.id_mer
GROUP BY te.id_tecnic
```

Comment: any query you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes I have tried that.

Update main post...

Comment: Hint: `LEFT JOIN` with approrpriate relationships, then do a `GROUP BY` on `id_technic` and caclulate the `SUM(..)` as required.

Comment: @Sylar [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57907122/edit) the question and add the attempted query there with the attempted query's result also.

Comment: What result you are getting from your query?

Comment: @Sylar just change `SUM(m.price)` to `COALESCE(SUM(m.price), 0)` to handle `NULL` values (in case there is nothing to sum for a specific `id_technic`).

Comment: Madhur Bhaiya, very thanks this is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Billy doesn't have record in `Table 2 - Linked` so with purpose to have Billy in result set you have to start from table `Table 3 - Mer`, like:

```
SELECT te.id_tecnic, te.name, SUM(m.price)
FROM mer m
LEFT jOIN linked l ON l.id_mer = m.id_mer
LEFT JOIN te ON te.id_tecnic = l.id_tecnic
GROUP BY te.id_tecnic;
```

Comment: Erm, you have to start from Billy.

Comment: @Strawberry yeah, true.